# calling jframe methods from constructor

Tags: java, swing, constructor

Are there any problems in calling methods from the constructor in this particular case?

```
    class GUI2
{
    JFrame jfrm;
    static Container cntr;
    GUI2(){

        jfrm=new JFrame("Raaga");
        jfrm.setSize(555,493);
        jfrm.setResizable(false);
        jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jfrm.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        jfrm.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Comment: Why should there be? What problems do you expect?

Answer (score 3):

There would be no problems if you write so. Ofcourse,writing too much business logic is not a good practice,IMO.

If you still can't avoid, in such cases  create a method and do there.That should be more readable.

```
GUI2(){
    intialize();    
}
```

And write logic there.

```
  private void intialize(){
        jfrm=new JFrame("Raaga");
        jfrm.setSize(555,493);
        jfrm.setResizable(false);
        jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jfrm.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        jfrm.setVisible(true);       
  }
```

Comment: I wouldn't call UI initializing business logic ;-)

Comment: @stonedsquirrel :) That logic in the sense.Adding conditions/checks.For ex:adding 2 buttons ,a combobox to frame based on a condition.

Comment: Point taken :-) but this is not the case here