# Is it good practice to create objects when creating a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, object, jframe, instantiation

The title does not say much and I apologize for that. I wasn't sure exactly how to explain my problem in a single sentence, so I tried my best. Anyways, to my question. Right now here's what I do:

```
public DeltaMain(int x, int y) {
    frame.setSize(x, y);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    new SoundButton(); // I have more buttons after this, I instantize each one.
    frame.add(sound);
}
```

And I just instantiate the `DeltaMain` class to load it. Is this good practice?

Comment: I'd say this isn't good practice. Also, you'll want to add components to the container *before* it's realized (i.e. made visible).

Comment: Answered here today :) ,MIght useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844405/calling-jframe-methods-from-constructor/18844605#18844605

Comment: *"Is this good practice?"*  Cannot speak to the wider 'practices' question, but that code snippet has a fearsome wreak to it.  *`frame.setSize(x, y);`*  Don't do that.  Add components **then** call `pack()`. *`frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);`* Change to `frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);` for a better result.  `frame.setVisible(true);` Do this ***after*** adding components and calling `pack()`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most people create a `initGUI()` method for this. I think it's a good idea to put everything into a `initGUI()` method, I also like the idea of listing all GUI components as protected members of the class.

This comes in very handy if you want to use your frame or panel in a subclass and overwrite/tweak some things to the needs of the subclass. If you do everything in the constructor it's all or nothing, makeing subclassing almost useless.